# what table material is electric oven safe to place on to?

Tags: oven

we have very limited space in the kitchen and the electric oven could not fit into it. Our only option is to put it on top of our glass dining table or buy a new table to the sides. I can't find any information on what are the best materials of the table top to put on the electric oven.

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: More information about the oven would be helpful. Can you point us to an actual model, or at least a type? If it is built to sit on the counter, and your glass table can support the weight, then it should be fine on the table. But I'd like to be sure to understand your question before I answer.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I went to the hardware store and bought a nice, wide ceramic tile in the flooring section.  I put some dollar-store felt feet on the underside to prevent scratching, so I can put it anywhere. That is what I set under my little oven when I use it, and it has given me no problems in five years.